# Is it possible to upload files directly to Amazon S3 using titanium appcelerator?

Tags: iphone, android, titanium, appcelerator

Im doing some research to build an iOS and Android app using titanium appcelerator. The only requirement I have not being able to confirm is the possibility to upload a photo directly to Amazon S3 in a way that is **compatible with iOS and Android devices**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 has provided a [REST API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/index.html?RESTAPI.html) so your can do it by creating a Titanium.Network.HTTPClient. For your upload case, you need to provide a PUT request to S3.
If you want to do it in this way, you may need to include your S3 secret key in your client for signing your request.

Comment: I think we will generate the signature server side. I don't want to include the accounts secret key in a javascript file with the app.

Answer (score 0):

You might ask the developers of Titanium Appcelerator. But if you're not writing an HTML5 app, you can definitely do this with the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3) framework.